# how to understand this operator

Tags: sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

In Sobolev space $H^1(\mathbb R^6)$, how do we understand $$\langle f(x,y),(-\Delta_x) f(x,y) \rangle $$ where $f\in H^1(\mathbb R^6)$ and $x\in \mathbb R^3$, $y\in \mathbb R^3$.

Comment: "How do we understand it" is a little vague - it would be better if you asked a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

$\Delta_x$ maps $H^1(\mathbb{R}^6)$ inside $H^0(\mathbb{R}^6) = L^2(\mathbb{R}^6)$. That will tell you how to justify your computation.

Comment: I knew in $H^1(\mathbb R^6)$ we can write $$\langle f(x,y),(-\Delta_x)(-\Delta_y)f(x,y) \rangle = \int_{\mathbb R^6}|2\pi k^2| |\widehat{f}(k)|^2{\rm d}k.$$ Can you help me to compute $\langle f(x,y),(-\Delta_x)f(x,y) \rangle $ in term of Fourier transform?.